# Weblogic 12c REP-501: The specified database cannot be connected

Tags: oracle, weblogic, weblogic12c, oraclereports, oracle-fusion-middleware

I have a problem when executing it outside the form builder,

from the call

http: // localhost: 9001 / forms / frmservlet? Config = webutil_webstart

1. the report works well from the formbuilder and runs smoothly
2. but when executing it from the direct url, I do not run the report,

I do the validation on the server with showjobs the error that I have is

The report ended in error:
REP-501: The specified database can not be connected ..

Maybe you can give me a hand where I would be missing some configuration.

thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you get to port 9001 in principle from the external box, like when you use telnet, for example?

Comment: Thank you for answering, making the validation I have access to port 9001

Answer (score 1):

look at your `db alias`(assume `mydb01`) in `tnsnames.ora` file under these paths:

`$ORACLE_INSTANCE/config` for `Linux` or `Solaris`.

maybe like `C:\Oracle\Middleware\asinst_1\config` for `Windows`.

Try to ping that alias like :

```
tnsping mydb01
```

if succeeds, use it for your connections.

During call of `run_report_object()` you have some parameter settings, whilst you may have such alike statement :

```
hidden_action := hidden_action ||’&userid=’
||get_application_property(username)||’/’||
get_application_property(password)||’@’||
get_application_property(connect_string);
```

Look at this arguments (connect_string,username&password) whether be set truely.

Comment: thanks for answering, tnsping works without problems in the tns I have in tnsnames.ora, all the forms are executed without inconveniences and are connected to the base. transaction well, the problem is when executing the report with RUN_REPORT_OBJECT from the URL call (this calls the form) this gives the database connection error.

If I execute the form that calls the report from formbuilder I have no problems, it runs fine.

Comment: good morning, perform the tests with

hidden_action: = hidden_action ||
'& userid =' || get_application_property (username) || '/' ||
get_application_property (password) || '@' ||
get_application_property (connect_string);


SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY (repid, REPORT_OTHER, 'pfaction =' || hidden_action || '');

the result is the same, in formbuilder it works, but when I already run from the url the application, login, menu and finally the screen follows the error.

REP-501: The specified database can not be connected ..

Comment: @JoseLuisGarciaArcalle ok, i'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Linux. The issues is due to special character in your password that could not be interpreted. If you change the password in the database without special character or replace the spacial character with an underscore (_). It should work.

Answer (score 0):

"If you're on Linux. The issues is due to special character in your password that could not be interpreted. If you change the password in the database without special character or replace the spacial character with an underscore (_). It should work." previous POST

100% correct

I had # in my password changed to &23
and it worked

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP

Answer (score 0):

Edit The RWBuilder.bat

Add Two Lines

set TNS_ADMIN=C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\network\ADMIN

set ORACLE_HOME=C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home